# Entity (point) is not show in 3D mode of Cesium?

Tags: cesium, 3d-map

I've added an entity:

```
var debris = cesiumViewer.entities.add({
  position : { 
    value : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883, 1000) ,
    referenceFrame : Cesium.ReferenceFrame.FIXED 
  },
  point : {
    color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
    pixelSize : 6
  }
});
```

The point is shown in 2D and Columbus mode, but hidden in 3D mode. Also, in Columbus mode it looks like the altitude iz 0.

Added also `cesiumViewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;`

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
var debris = cesiumViewer.entities.add({

  position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883, 1000) ,  

  point : {
    color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
    pixelSize : 6
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify `ReferenceFrame.FIXED`, as that's the default.  Try this:

```
var debris = cesiumViewer.entities.add({
  position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883, 1000),
  point : {
    color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
    pixelSize : 6
  }
});
```

If you really do need to specify a reference frame, you can construct that like this:

```
var debris = cesiumViewer.entities.add({
  position : new Cesium.ConstantPositionProperty(
    Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883, 1000),
    Cesium.ReferenceFrame.FIXED 
  ),
  point : {
    color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
    pixelSize : 6
  }
});
```